# How to get record Id from Lightning record edit form on record insert

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-recordeditform

I have a requirement where I am making use of `lightning:recordEditForm` to create a new record. I am using standard save functionality. After successful save of record I need to make use of the record Id. Is there is any native way to get Id of record without making server call?

Following is my UI code

```
<lightning:recordEditForm  onsuccess="{!c.handleSuccess}" onerror="{!c.handleError}"
        aura:id="recordEditForm" 
      objectApiName="Address__c">

            <lightning:messages />

           <lightning:inputField fieldName="Customer__c" value="{!v.accountRecord.Id}" class='slds-hide'/> 

            <aura:iteration items="{!v.displayListAddress}" var="item" >
                <lightning:inputField fieldName="{!item}" onchange="{!c.fieldValChange}"/>                             
            </aura:iteration>  
        <div class="slds-modal__footer">
           <div class="slds-align_absolute-center">
              <lightning:button label="Cancel" title="Neutral action" onclick="{! c.closeEdit }"/>
              <lightning:button variant="brand" type="submit" name="save" label="Save" />
           </div>
        </div>
```

I thought that after successful record creation the recordId attribute will get populated with appropriate value and will give proper value via this

```
alert("Id : "+component.find("recordEditForm").get("v.recordId"));
```

But this returns undefined.

Though I can make a server call with appropriate filters in SOQL to get Id of the record, but seems there should be some easier way around without server call.

Answer (score 5):

the [component documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordEditForm/documentation) has a sample snippet for you to do so.

using the onsuccess event, you have access to the response object which contains, amongst other things, the id of the record that was recently created:

```
({
    handleSuccess : function(component, event, helper) {
        var payload = event.getParams().response;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(payload));
    }    
})
```

> The response data associated with the record during a record create or
>   edit.
>
> - apiName: The record's API name, such as Contact.
> - childRelationships: The child relationship data for this record.
> - fields: The field data for this record, matching the requested layout.
> - id: The ID of this record.
> - recordTypeInfo: The record type info for this record, if any.